# How can we update or edit meta fields for each product for getting multiple images of each product from shopify?

Tags: javascript, next.js, shopify, algolia

How can we update or edit meta fields for each product for getting  multiple images of each product from shopify ?

Comment: Not sure I've heard of a "met product" before on Shopify, maybe you mean "meta" or something? But have you tried tanking a gander at the docs for bulk editing: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/shopify-admin/productivity-tools/bulk-editing

Comment: yes meta fields

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to have multiple images per product and set in the metafields of the product which image corresponds to which feature of the product.

I would suggest the following, possibly using a web application or an app that removes any manual intervention:

- You upload all the pictures of the product using Shopify API (or manually).
- You create a metafield attribute with a json that contains the map the index of the picture that you upload.
- In your .liquid file you access pictures with something like `product.media[product.metafields.myshop.media_data['front_picture']]`

To make an example, let's say you have a product with 4 front and 5 back pictures.

- You upload all your pictures. Front pictures are first 4 and back are the last ones (this is just an example, they could be mixed).
- You set your metafield as      `{ "front" : [1,2,3,4],"back" : [5,6,7,8,9]}` (NB they don't have to be consequent numbers)
- In your frontend you can put

```
    {% for front_index in product.metafields.myshop.media_data.front %}
          <img src="{{ product.media[front_index]| img_url: 'original' }}"/>
    {% endfor %}
```